# Обособление приложений — имён собственных

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложения

Всем ещё раз здравствуйте!.. Есть следующий вопрос: нужна ли в данном предложении указанная  запятая, т. е. является ли здесь это название завода обособленным приложением?..

*В Кургане построен мощный завод с новейшим станочным парком(,) "Курганспецарматура".*

Всем большущее спасибо заранее за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Если приложение и(или) определяемое слово имеют зависимые слова, то приложение выделяется с обеих сторон запятыми, за исключением тех случаев, когда необходимо ставить тире.

Осталось проверить нужно ли тире.

Приложения выделяются тире в следующих случаях:

1. приложение носит пояснительный характер, перед тире можно поставить или стоят слова а именно, то есть. В дальнем углу светилось желтое пятно – огонь в окне квартиры Серафимы, пристроенной к стене конюшни.;
2. приложение относится к слову, стоящему в ряду однородных. В вазе стояли ромашки – желтоглазые цветы, колокольчики и лютики. Приложение желтоглазые цветы определяет слово ромашки. Если это приложение выделить запятыми, тогда его можно будет перепутать с однородным: В вазе стояли ромашки, желтоглазые цветы, колокольчики и лютики. Можно подумать, что желтоглазые цветы – не ромашки, а астры, например, тоже стоящие в вазе, поэтому приложения в таких случаях отделяют со стороны определяемого слова тире.;
3. приложение заканчивает предложение. В вазе стояли ромашки – желтоглазые цветы.

В данном случае "Курганспецарматура" это приложение, а "завод" определяемое слово, так как именно оно согласуется со сказуемым. Получается, приложение заканчивает предложение. В таком случае ставится тире.

```
В Кургане построен мощный завод с новейшим станочным парком - "Курганспецарматура".
```

[Справочник с правилом](https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)